# CRON job outputting blank lines

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, scheduled-tasks

I tried to create a CRON job that runs every minute. As a root user, I ran `crontab -e`, and in the cronjob, I put in my command  `* * * * * /usr/bin/php {redacted}/index.php > {redacted}/output.txt`

the `{redacted}` file path has permissions added: `chmod ogu+rwx -R` so everyone should be able to access it. I even created a new user with no sudo or root privileges, and running `/usr/bin/php {redacted}/index.php > {redacted}/output.txt` obviously writes the output of `{redacted}/index.php` to `{redacted}/output.txt`. However, my cron job ends up overwriting and turning the .txt file to just blank, nothing. I have no idea what is going on since I already made sure there were no permission errors, and cron jobs don't seem to have a visible log or output?

I would love to have any ideas about this. I even tried to add the cron job  `* * * * * root /usr/bin/php {redacted}/index.php > {redacted}/output.txt`, all to the same output.

One more thing... I have tried to set the `{redacted}` location to `/var/www/html`, `/var/www/{a user with sudo perms}`, and `{/usr/local/bin}` all with the same result.

Update:
I tried something as simple as `* * * * * php -v > {redacted}/output.txt` and `* * * * * /usr/bin/php -v > {redacted}/output.txt` still with the same result, so it seems like the error is not with requiring root permissions to run my php program

Comment: Add `2>&1` to the end of the command. You're probably getting errors, and this will write the error messages to the file as well.

Comment: Are you trying to run a script that normally runs as a web page? If it tries to use things like `$_SESSION` or `$_POST` this won't work when it's from from a CLI.

Comment: ill trya that '2>&1' really quick. No its not a webpage, its a script that hits and oracle cloud API endpoint for provisioning services

Comment: Alright, so I added the 2>&1 to the end of the command, and it seems like I am getting the same blank file output

Comment: If you run the script by hand from a terminal, you get the expected output?

Comment: Yup! runs as per expected by hand on root, sudo account and regular account (no sudo access)

Comment: Is it just this script, or do you have to same problem with a simple `<?php echo "Hello world\n";` script?

Comment: so I tried both.... I had a .sh script that would run the php and output the files to the log file, no problems running that as root, sudo account and non-sudo account by hand, and had the same issue when running by cron task. I also tried cron tasking it for running it by php directly (something like php index.php) and had this same issue